# Dynamically change font-family and font-size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the fonts and size of the text dynamically

but I don't see any answer in the browser and also no errors in my code
this is **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mkafiyan/fZVK5/)**

html:

```
<body>
<form id="texteditor">
    <select id="font">
        <option value="School">School</option>
        <option value="SansitaOne">SansitaOne</option>
        <option value="oliver">oliver</option>
        <option value="JuraLight">Jura-Light-webfont</option>
        <option value="Jura">Jura-DemiBold-webfont</option>
        <option value="DJGROSS">DJGROSS-webfont</option>
        <option value="College">College</option>
        <option value="BYekan">BYekan</option>
        <option value="BRoya">BRoya</option>
        <option value="BMitraBold">BMitraBold</option>
        <option value="BMitra">BMitra</option>
    </select>
    <select id="size">
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
    </select>
</form>
<textarea class="changeme">this is my text example !!!</textarea>
</body>
```

jquery :

```
$("#font").change(function() {
//alert($(this).val());
$('.changeMe').css("font-family", $(this).val());

  });



 $("#size").change(function() {
 $('.changeMe').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
 });
```

Comment: Simply add and remove classes: `addClass()` and `removeClass()`?

Comment: I don't understand what u say very well!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from not including jQuery in the example, you had a typo.

`$('.changeMe')` should be `$('.changeme')`

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QEk2v/)

```
$("#font").change(function() {
    $('.changeme').css("font-family", $(this).val());

});

$("#size").change(function() {
    $('.changeme').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});
```

Comment: my jsfiddle example is correct now but when I add this changes in my code , it doesn't answer

Comment: @mimi It changes the CSS, but it's not working because those fonts don't exist. The CSS `url`'s are not accessing anything. Look at this example with a google font: http://jsfiddle.net/45dyx/