# Extension for font family changer

Tags: joomla, fonts, joomla-extensions, font-family

is there any extension to change whole website's font family by using drop down? I only found extension for font resize and color.

[dropdown to change font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H4li.png)

Comment: why not create it yourself? all you need is to add the coding for the dropdown and the css. This can be done within a module and to additions to the css.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a module to do this either.

It would probably be fairly easy to modify one of the extensions that switches font size or colour to handle font family instead or create this yourself.

There is some example code to do this at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22287158/1983389